# How to find inspiring funny posts?

Tags: support, search, fun

Some answers or comments are highly upvoted not just for being great, some of them gain lots of popularity also because of their style, mostly because they are funny somehow.

Sometimes when I'm sad or tired, posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/343721) really helps me to regain my enthusiasm essential for productive coding. I'd like to search them somehow. Is it possible? Would it be against the purpose of this site?

Comment: No, I'm afraid there's no funny:1 search operator.

Comment: There are not many of those funnies left any more, as they have become increasingly off-topic, and many deleted. I recommend places like http://theonion.com

Comment: The fact that they're deleted makes a small part of me sad. I mean, I get it, and I totally back the decision. They're not good questions. But it's a culture, and it's disappointing to see small parts of it cut away.

Comment: just search things by max number of votes; [The Trouble With Popularity](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/) typically helps to bring funny garbage up. See also: [Popular Deleted SO/SU/Programmers Questions list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73455/165773)